# FLASK render_template specify template folder each time

Tags: python, templates, flask

I want to implement customization of templates into my flask application. My problem is, the custom template folder is not the same as default.

Is it possible to use the function render_template() and specify the template directory each time I use render_template ?

Comment: I see this one. But it's 7 years old and I think this is not compatible with newer version of Flask :/

Comment: It is compatible with Python 3.8.2 and 1.1.2 for me. I just tested it.

Comment: Okay i'll test it, thanks !

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks :) Do you know if it's possible to makes the same but with static folder ?